# In a Google Sheets chart how do I prevent "Other" in the legend?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

When there are over 8 series in a chart (this is true at least for a pie chart) - Sheets combines all other series above the 8th into "Other" this is really counter productive when there are only 9 series... It could have just shown the last series instead of change the label to "Other".

Anyway, is there any way to stop this behavior manually?

The only solution I can think of is doctoring the image and replacing the "Other" with the label of the 9th series.

---

**Edit: This behaviour doesn't happen anymore. No need for answers.**

Comment: Can you share the sheet so we can take a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Comment

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[how do I prevent “Other” in the legend?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14yEvmuMz7nnL040pRdiVBHKxxc0tmKpG5R_jU3Sj4o4/edit?usp=sharing)**

### Update

I've done some research and found out the following in which the behavior can be resolved if shown:

1. Choose an exact range in the chart: I2:I107
2. Delete the remaining empty rows, in your sheet

Comment: Thanks for answering this really old question! The behaviour I was struggling with doesn't happen any more. Google Sheets have evolved considerably in the last couple of years...